# How to set RingCentral limits

Tags: twilio, sms, voip, ringcentral

I need to be able to set daily limits on Ringcentral to protect ourselves in the unlikely event of someone getting ahold of our log in credentials...ie. FRAUD.

Is there a way to set upper daily limits on the account?

If not, is there a way to monitor the account and then suspend it, all programmatically?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any such system in RingCentral currently that will monitor RingCentral account and provide configuring protocols and setting the restriction on it.
They always encourage to put these ideas in their idea portal [here](https://ideas.ringcentral.com/) for future implementation.
In case of any Fraud detection it is advised to contact their support team manually.